# Is there a way to upload the full WordPress "Builders Landing Page" theme DEMO to a new WordPress account?

Tags: wordpress, themes

Is there a way to upload the full WordPress "Builders Landing Page" theme DEMO to a new WordPress account? I tried uploading the full theme Demo and only the blog portion is uploading.

I clicked on the "Activate" theme from the WP Appearance tab and went to import the Demo but the full demo isn't uploading to the site.

Theme link: 
https://wordpress.org/themes/builders-landing-page/

Comment: Have you contacted theme support?

Comment: No only because i heard if you contacted support it isn't free!

Comment: Try https://wordpress.org/support/theme/builders-landing-page/